# Calling php functions using concatenation - $newArticle->setInternationalText.$i();

Tags: php, symfony, for-loop, concatenation

I have eight php functions. They are:

```
setInternationalText1()

setInternationalText2()

setInternationalText3()

...etc
```

I want to call these functions all at once using minimal code. I have tried using a `for loop` but PHP doesnt seem to allow me to concatinate my '`counter`' variable onto the end of a function name. See below...

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 8; $i++)
{  
   $newArticle->setInternationalText.$i();
}
```

The above gives me the following (symfony) error:

```
Notice: Undefined property: Imagine\NewsletterBundle\Entity\Article::$setInternationalText in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/newsletters/src/Imagine/NewsletterBundle/Controller/SectionController.php line 260
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the call_user_func() function:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 8; $i++)
{
    $fn = 'setInternationalText'.$i;
    call_user_func(array($newArticle,$fn));
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php

Comment: Cool. Where do I pass in my function parameters though?

Comment: If you want to pass them one by one, you can do that like this: call_user_func(array($newArticle,$fn),$param1,$param2,...); OR you can use an array: $params = array('1','2','3'); call_user_func_array(array($newArticle,$fn),$params);

Answer (score 3):

The right syntax is:

```
$newArticle->{setInternationalText . $i}();
```